# Delete a Perforce client workspace with pending files when the workspace has already been removed from disk?

Tags: version-control, perforce

How do I delete a workspace that has pending files when that workspace has already been removed from disk?

## Caveats:

- p4 command line only; not p4v gui
- regular user access; no admin access

## Scenario:

- create a workspace named `user_workspace` on the disk in the `~/my_workspace` directory
- p4 edit files in workspace on the default pending changelist
- remove workspace by hand (`rm -rf ~/my_workspace`)

  - workspace still exists on server with pending files

## Solutions that don't work:

### 1: Delete workspace

Doesn't work because the workspace has files opened.

`p4 client -d user_workspace`

Client 'user_workspace' has files opened; use -f to force delete.

### 2: Delete workspace with force

Doesn't work because not admin.

`p4 client -d -f user_workspace`

You don't have permission for this operation.

### 3: Delete the pending changelist; then delete workspace (try 1)

`p4 changes -c user_workspace -s pending`

Only lists pending numbered changelists, does not handle the default pending changelist.

`p4 -c user_workspace -d changelist_number`

Not possible because there is no changelist number for the pending changelist.

### 4: Delete the pending changelist; then delete workspace (try 2)

Trying to do a p4 revert on a directory that does not exist anymore gives a strange error.

`p4 revert ~/my_workspace`

/home/user/my_workspace - must refer to client 'user_workspace'.

`p4 -c user_workspace revert ~/my_workspace`

/home/user/my_workspace - must refer to client 'user_workspace'.

`setenv P4CLIENT user_workspace; p4 -c user_workspace revert ~/my_workspace`

/home/user/my_workspace - must refer to client 'user_workspace'.

Comment: `-c` is now `changelists` with the latest version of p4.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## 1. Revert the pending changelist

Have to use Perforce depot notation instead of local directory notation because the local directory does not exist anymore.

`p4 -c user_workspace revert -k //...`

//blah/blah/blah/file#rev - was edit, reverted

## 2. Delete the client workspace

`p4 client -d user_workspace`

Client user_workspace deleted.

Comment: For #1, there's an additional step necessary. You need to perform p4 ... revert -k //... which will bypass the client step and only make the change on the server. Otherwise, you'll keep failing because the local files can't be changed if the directory structure doesn't exist or isn't writable.

Comment: I got invalid option -k. [-a -n -c changelist#] -a fixed the issue.

Comment: If you get an error when trying to delete because your not in an existing client workspace, you can try `p4 -c user_workspace client -d user_workspace`.

Answer (score 6):

this will give you the pending changes on the client

```
p4 changes -c user_workspace
```

this will delete the pending change list of your choice

```
p4 change -d <change list number>
```

after that, you can delete the client using

```
p4 client -d user_workspace
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for the case where I was trying to delete a workspace without deleting its changelist

Answer (score 3):

The command line did not work for me. It kept reporting "over license quota" for any commands. I probably have something configured wrong related to that. This would mean I would have to first correct that problem and then use the above solution. However, I found another way to fix this issue using the p4v client.

The junk workspaces were old workspaces from my previous computer. Those without any files checked out I was able to right-click delete in the workspaces tab view. Those workspaces with files left checked out I was not able to remove as other are experiencing. To removes these I had to take a few extra steps.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

*** Alternatively: Try these four step using only the p4v client ***

1. Edit the workspace and just blank out the host field of the old workspace. In another thread I read this allows editing from any computer.
2. Switch to the workspace
3. Revert the files in the WORKSPACE view; there was no need to sync the files to my local machine
4. Delete the workspace after switching back to the workspaces tab.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Wrote this script called **[p4-delete-client](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u/blob/master/p4-delete-client)** for deleting a p4 client (which has changelists & other problems).
It has the following features:

- automatically deletes changelists (reverts pending & deletes shelved)
- fixes hostname (if differs from the one the client was created on)
- unlocks the client if locked
- deletes the client
- deletes associated files (can be configured not to from arguments)

> Note that the script relies on other scripts in the [repo](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u).

Answer (score -1):

The rm -rf command only deleted files on your system, the workspace still exists in perforce. If you want to delete it, you have to revert the files first.

p4 revert ~/my_workspace
p4 client -d user_workspace

Comment: "p4 revert ~/my_workspace" gives error: "~/my_workspace - must refer to client 'user_workspace'."